# Passportjs (after successful login)

Tags: angularjs, node.js, passport.js

I have the following code borrowed from this excellent resource: http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/easy-node-authentication-setup-and-local#handling-signup/registration

```
app.post('/signup', passport.authenticate('local-signup', {
    successRedirect : '/profile', // redirect to the secure profile section
    failureRedirect : '/signup', // redirect back to the signup page if there is an error
}));
```

but I don't want to use the `successRedirect` or `failureRedirect` as my front end is an Angularjs app. If the signup was successful I want to tell my Angularjs front end but how can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of doing:

```
app.post('/signup', passport.authenticate('local-signup', {
  successRedirect : '/profile', // redirect to the secure profile section
  failureRedirect : '/signup', // redirect back to the signup page if there is an error
}));
```

You can do something like:

```
app.post('/signup', function(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('local-signup', function(err, user, info) {
    if (err) {
      return next(err); // will generate a 500 error
    }
    // Generate a JSON response reflecting signup
    if (! user) {
      return res.send({ success : false, message : 'signupfailed' });
    }
    return res.send({ success : true, message : 'signup succeeded' });
  })(req, res, next);
});
```

For more details go to http://passportjs.org/guide/authenticate/ and look at the Custom Callback section at the bottom.

Comment: thanks for this - so you think I should move the auth logic back out of my separate passport.js file and into my routes.js file?

Comment: No need 'local-signup' is the named strategy for the authentication process. Per that article passport.use('local-signup', new LocalStrategy({... so when you call passport.authenticate('local-signup' it will look for that strategy and use the process setup there.

Comment: one silly question but why is there an authentication process for a signup in Passport? If I was making my own system I wouldn't authenticate a user until after they had signed up. Does it log them in when they register?

Comment: What the article is showing is that you can have many strategies with passport and depending on which named strategy is used with the authenticate method will have different results. If you look they have a local-login and local-signup. local-signup creates the user and authenticates them whereas local-login only authenticates them.